# Update one column based on matching values of two columns from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have 3 columns, like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| startpoint  |  endpoint   | number |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 15037232632 |  4226861620 | null   |
|  4226862003 |  4226862079 | null   |
|  4226862079 |  4226862111 | null   |
|  4226862111 |  4226862121 | 2      |
|  4226862121 |  ---------- | 1      |
| 15025374738 |  4226862003 | null   |
|  4226861620 | 15025374738 | null   |
|  4226801794 | 15037232632 | null   |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

**What I am trying to do is:**

Step 1 : I assign a number '1' to any one of the IDs from the 'startpoint' column

Step 2 : Match the 'startpoint' ID to which I assigned the number in the previous step with the IDs in the 'endpoint' column

Step 3 : After the 'startpoint' ID matches with the 'endpoint' ID, I assign the number 2 in the 'number' column on the ROW where the endpoint matched

Step 4: On the row where number was assigned, I take the 'startpoint' ID and then repeat the steps 2-4 again.

I have tried playing around with the update query but it doesn't seem right. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am also including the expected output. The table without applying any queries is given above

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| startpoint  |  endpoint   | number |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 15037232632 | 4226861620  |      7 |
|  4226862003 | 4226862079  |      4 |
|  4226862079 | 4226862111  |      3 |
|  4226862111 | 4226862121  |      2 |
|  4226862121 | ----------  |      1 |
| 15025374738 | 4226862003  |      5 |
|  4226861620 | 15025374738 |      6 |
|  4226801794 | 15037232632 |      8 |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: You should at the very least also include the exact output you expect.  Depending on which record you start with, the output would change IIUC.

Comment: Sure, I'll add that to the main post. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Would there be any duplicates in any of the `startpoint` and `endpoint` columns?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility @tcadidot0

Comment: I think you are looking are recursion - what version of mysql are you on.